# Organising AngularJS Modules

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting with Angular and trying to get my head around modules.

My project has two parts, which I would consider modules ( names and places ) and I also have generic controllers that are used in general on the site.

My question is, how to organise these? (code examples)

For example, I have this generic controller:

```
fb.controller( 'textareaGrow', function( $scope, $element ) {
var update = function() {
    var s = $element[0].scrollHeight;
    var h = $element[0].offsetHeight;
    if( s > h )
        $element.css( 'height', ( s - 26 ) + 'px' );
}
$element.bind( 'keyup keydown keypress change', update );
update();
});
```

Do I just change this to:

```
angular.module('fb.generic', []).controller( 'textareaGrow',
```

Or, as in the example I am looking at, is the etiquette to group into modules by type? The example I am looking at has modules for: controllers, factories, services etc.

Comment: You're free to organize them by functionality, by type, or both. Everyone has its preferences, and it depends on the size of the application, the way it's developed, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious method for breaking up our app by modules is to divide the modules by type.

We need to inject these modules as dependencies for our main app, which makes it incredibly easy
to set up tests for each module type and also isolates and subdivides the functionality that we’ll need
to account for when writing specs.
For instance, we can create a module for each Angular object type:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []);
    angular.module('myApp.services', []);
    angular.module('myApp.filters', []);
    // Often time we'll want to use our services
    // inside of our controllers, so we'll inject
    // those into our 'myApp.controllers' module
    angular.module('myApp.controllers', [
   'myApp.services'
]);
angular.module('myApp', [
   'myApp.directives',
   'myApp.controllers',
   'myApp.filters',
   'myApp.services'
]);
```

One issue with this method is that it sometimes leaves us with a bunch of incredibly small modules.

**This outcome won’t hurt performance, but it can be cumbersome to develop.
Modularize on Routes**

Another method we can use to break up our app is to divide our modules by route. This breakdown
allows us to write isolated tests that focus on the functionality per route. Modularizing by route can
make more sense, depending upon the project; it allows us to divide our functionality efficiently
when we’re dealing with a lot of independent routes.
For instance:

```
angular.module('myApp.home', []);
angular.module('myApp.login', []);
angular.module('myApp.account', []);
angular.module('myApp', [
   'myApp.home',
   'myApp.login',
   'myApp.account'
]);
```

This modularization makes sense specifically when we’re dealing with large numbers of routes
and/or when we don’t have too much cross-over between routes

from [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/)

Comment: Thank you. So by organising by type, you can include whatever Javascript files you need for a page, Angular will build the modules; but you may have other JavaScript files that attach to those modules that you are not using?

Comment: I didnt get you question ? what you mean by asking angular build modules ? modules building you

Comment: It's hard to explain. But, essentially, by grouping your modules by type (controller etc.), that module can potentially have different controllers (depending on what JS you load). For example, you could load 10 controllers to fb.controllers, 5 factories to fb.factories for one page, but 4 controllers and 10 factories for another. Thus, you can use a lot of common components, and not include ones you don't need. I like the flexibility of this.

Comment: then you can choose the based on rout, and for example instantiate your controller and servecies depend on your route